# Outlook Add-in: deploying new version does not update in outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, add-in, appsource

I am currently working on an existing office 365 outlook add-in.
I'm not using visual studio but eclipse on a mac.
I simply need to do some debugging to check the response of an API call, so I added my debug code and deployed the add-in on the hosted server.

Then, from the Office Admin Center  I re-upload the add-in making it available to all users.

The original problem was that the updated version of the add-in did not update straight away in outlook.

I left it for a day and today outlook was serving the updated add-in but then I had to add some more debugging code and once redeployed the new add-in version again was not served in outlook.

Thinking it was a caching issue I deleted all the browser cache (Local Storage, Session Storage, Cache Storage).

Unfortunately since then the Add-in is not loading at all returning an Add-in error:

> Uncaught Function ContextActivationManager_getAppContextAsync call failed. ErrorCode is -2, exception: Failed origin check
>
> from outlook-web-16.01.js

I tried to re-deploy it updating the version in the manifest but still no success.
I cannot really afford to waste another day to wait for the new version to kick-in so I was wondering if there is a faster way? Am I doing something wrong in deploying the add-in? Is there a reason why uploading a new version of the add-in it doesn't get served straight away in outlook?

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED. Apparently there is nothing wrong with the add-in deployment. I have spoken directly to the outlook support team and they said that if you are using the outlook web app the plugin takes time to become available because it goes through a release process.
So either use the desktop version of outlook or wait at least half hour before the plugin finally becomes available.

The error I mentioned earlier looks like it is not related to the add-in deployment.